# Edit Facebook Like Button to make button into link?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I've always just used a thumbnail to link to my Facebook Fan Page and a Like button for individual content. But I'd like to combine the two into one button so that it shows the number of people who have Liked my website next to a button which takes them directly to my Fan Page. SlickDeals does exactly what I'm looking for here (top left corner): http://archive.slickdeals.net/ Any idea on how I can do this too?

Answer (score 0):

I think the slickdeals fan status is a proprietary customization - simple one indeed. You might try to mimic their code.

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/slickdeals" target="_blank" title="82,851 Fans"><img src="http://st.slickdealz.net/images/iconrepo/social2/16px/facebook.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
<img src="http://st.slickdealz.net/images/iconrepo/social2/16px/facebook.png" width="16" height="16">
<span class="triangle-border" title="82,851 Fans">83K</span>
```

However, Facebook provides a plugin to create Like buttons http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ that is much more powerful and easier.